# Too broad / recommendation / opinion-based question or not?

Tags: discussion, disputed-review-audits

**edit:** I see the original question is almost closed.  But it appears that the author is looking at modifying the original question, so perhaps it's worth holding off on voting to close

---

So I failed a triage audit. https://stackoverflow.com/review/triage/9685631

And the questioner obviously had higher reputation than me, so I knew something was up.

Here's the question:

[MSDeploy vs WebDeploy vs Publish-AzureWebsiteProject vs dnu publish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32623448/msdeploy-vs-webdeploy-vs-publish-azurewebsiteproject-vs-dnu-publish)

It lists 4 different tools for publishing apps and then asks "What are the main differences between them and when should/could they be used?"  Already that "and" makes it look like it's asking 2 questions, and it looks likely to get opinion-based answers.

The fact that two weeks later neither of the answers are accepted fits with the fact that I think it's too broad to get a clear answer.

So:

**What are the differences between "too broad", "opinion-based" and "asking us to recommend something", and when should I use or not use them?**

Or to make the question specific:  Should one of these apply to the question, and if not, why not?

Comment: The only objective of participating in an audit is to not fail it.  And if you declare an audit question unsalveable when it has 9 upvotes and two upvoted answers then you'll of course fail the audit.  Probably because you were not paying attention, the one thing that audits check.  Stop, look, listen.

Comment: @HansPassant "Probably because you were not paying attention".  Sorry - I find this insulting, and I don't think you can reach that conclusion fairly from reading my question.  I was paying attention.

Comment: Hmya, you can't really expect SO users to understand what the point might be of intentionally failing audits.  Not a lot of them graduated from school by intentionally failing exams.  Just click the Skip button.

Comment: @HansPassant Perhaps the issue is that since I have less experience than you, assuming that my choices are informed by the same knowledge you have would be wrong.  I thought it was likely that this was testing whether I would auto-click "looks fine" if it appeared to be from a high-rep user.  I realize that based on your background it was easy to attribute it to laziness on my part, but it would be equally easy for me to attribute your conclusion and choice to express it the way you did as a personal failing on your part.

Comment: *What are the differences between "too broad", "opinion-based" and "asking us to recommend something", **AND** when should I use or not use them?*  Looks like your question is too broad ;-)

Comment: @TimCastelijns Thanks!  I was hoping someone would appreciate the humor.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That is unfortunate and I'm not sure if I would have successfully made it past that audit. Although that high-rep user and then choosing Unsalvageable feels counter intuitive so I probably visited the question before I would have voted. From that I would have learned that Unsalvageable was not something the community agreed on.

Your analysis however is sound and correct. That question is not asking about a practical problem, it is a kind of design question that can be answered by giving enough context as you can see from the two answers. One of the answers even claims that the list of options is not complete.

The voting on the question reveals that more members struggle with all the options they have so they were glad someone asked it and up voted it accordingly.

I do think the question has some value and answers certainly have so I'm torn between the options we have on how to handle this. I'll think about an edit that makes that question less of asking for opinions and more about the practicality of each possible way of doing those things.

I left a close vote on the question for now. That should take it out the audit for triage I think so no more users will be tripped by this.

Now lets hope that question can get a good edit so I can retract my close vote again.